# How to display message in dialog while clicking command button with ajax=false in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use inputText, commandButton and uploadFile components. In commandButton, i have used ajax=false and made required=true in both the fields. When click on save with empty values, error message is not getting displayed in the dialog and dialog is getting closed. But in console, warning messages are displaying like "Messages are rendered but not displayed".

Below is my code:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="addDialogWidgetVar" id="addDialogWidgetVarId"  dynamic="true" >

            <table  style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p:messages for="errorMsgId" id="errorMsgId" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" closable="true"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            <h:form id="formId" enctype="multipart/form-data">



                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label style="margin-top: 5%"><h:outputText value="Name:"/><h:outputText value="*" style="color:red"/></label>
                        </td>
                        <td width="10%"/>
                        <td>
                            <p:inputText value="#{manageBean.attachment.fileName}" id="fileNameId" maxlength="60" style="width:70"
                                        required="#{not empty param[save.clientId]}" requiredMessage="Please enter Attachment name"></p:inputText>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="10"></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label style="margin-top: 5%"><h:outputText value="Upload Attachment:"/><h:outputText value="*" style="color:red"/></label>
                        </td>
                        <td width="10%"/>
                        <td>
                            <p:fileUpload label="Select a file" mode="simple" value="#{manageBean.attachment.file}"
                                        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG)$/"
                                        invalidFileMessage="Allow only (pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG) file."
                                        multiple="false" required="#{not empty param[save.clientId]}" requiredMessage="Please select a file" >
                            </p:fileUpload>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                    <table style="margin-left: 30%;">                           
                    <tr align="center">

                        <td>
                            <p:commandButton value="Close" actionListener="#{manageBean.cancelAttachment}" oncomplete="addDialogWidgetVar.hide()" />
                        </td>

                        <td> 
                            <p:commandButton id="submitbtnid" value="Save" ajax="false" binding="#{save}"
                                        actionListener="#{manageBean.saveAttachment}" update=":errorMsgId"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </h:form>

        </p:dialog>
```

When the values are empty, error message should be displayed in dialog itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expected behavior when you use `ajax=false` because on submit whole page is refreshed and that is why the dialog gets closed.

Also, in your `p:messages` component, you shouldn't have `for` attribute that points out to `errorMsgId`. In `for` you should put id of the input field you wan't to show messages from. For example, if you put `formId:fileNameId`, it will show error when you don't enter file name. But if you don't have `for`, it will show all the messages.

And you do not need `update=":errorMsgId"` since you have already put `autoUpdate="true"`.

Now, to accomplish what you need, and show messages with `ajax=false` without closing dialog, there is this workaround:

JSF (in place where your save button is defined): ***Save button redefined later**

```
<p:commandButton id="submitbtnid" **style="display:none"** ajax="false" binding="#{save}" actionListener="#{manageBean.saveAttachment}" />
<p:commandButton value="Save" oncomplete="checkIfValid(xhr, status, args)" />
```

And JavaScript function:

```
function checkIfValid(xhr, status, args)
  {
      if (!args.validationFailed)
      {
          $("#formId\\:submitbtnid").click();
      }
  }
```

So, here is visible button which uses ajax and calls JS method to check if validation failed. And only if all validation conditions passed, it will click invisible button which actually submits the form.

**UPDATE**

For fileUpload input there should be an extra check. In this way, you can remove allowTypes an required attributes from fileUpload component, and add it an id -  all validation will be in JavaScript function.

This is your fileUpload component:

```
<p:fileUpload label="Select a file" mode="simple" value="#{manageBean.attachment.file}" multiple="false"></p:fileUpload>
```

And you should also add hiddenInput in your form (and messageHidden field in your bean):

```
<h:inputHidden id="errorMsg" value="#{manageBean.messageHidden}"/>
```

Now, this is JavaScript function that does file input validation:

```
function checkFileInput() {
                if ($("#formId\\:fileInput")[0].files.length == 0) {
                    $("#formId\\:errorMsg").val("Please select a file");
                    return;
                }
                var validExtensions = ['pdf','doc','docx','xls','xlsx','gif','png','jpg','jpeg'];
                var maxFileSize = 5000;

                var ext = $('#formId\\:fileInput').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
                if($.inArray(ext, validExtensions) == -1) {
                    $("#formId\\:errorMsg").val("Allow only (pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG) file.");
                    return;
                }

                if ($("#formId\\:fileInput")[0].files[0].size > maxFileSize) {
                    $("#formId\\:errorMsg").val("File is to big");
                    return;
                }
                $("#formId\\:errorMsg").val("");
            }
```

It first checks if the file is selected, then its extension and then allowed file maximum size. And if something of that isn't valid, it sets new value to hidden input field.

Now, in your bean, you should check if file validation went OK:

```
public void validateFile() {
        if(!messageHidden.trim().equals("")) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();

            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, messageHidden, messageHidden);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        }
    }
```

If it didn't, validation failed will be set to the context and message from inputHidden will be added.

And, at last, you should change Save button to first check file input with JS, then validate it with bean method, and at the and check if validation failed:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" onclick="checkFileInput()" actionListener="#{testBean.validateFile}"
              oncomplete="checkIfValid(xhr, status, args)" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your answer is working for only input text, not for file upload component. How to validate file upload in simple mode and display the corresponding error message inside popup itself?